# Integrating web app with chrome extension

Tags: cookies, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which gets data from the current active tab in chrome. I send the data to my webapp via an API which stores it in the database.

At the moment my chrome extension has a fixed user_id. I would like to prompt the user the user to log in in order to get the correct user.

Is it safe/valid to check for cookie - if it exists use it otherwise prompt user to sign in via the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably okay, as long as you're not storing anything sensitive in the cookie like a password (obviously).

However, the appropriate way to accomplish this would be through something like oAuth. In this scenario your web app's API would be a oAuth consumer, and you would use the following library to authenticate in a Chrome extension:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html

This library will save an authentication to local storage for you. It's pretty easy to use. The difficult part is ensuring your web app's API supports OpenID. Google's AppEngine supports this pretty much out of the box with little configuration on your side, but this may not be the case with your API.